# Adding elements to the List inside setState() method, not saving element Flutter

Tags: list, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

I'm adding another list items to new List and performing this code inside the setState(). But whenever I call this class in which the new list is initialized, list's previous entry gets disappear.. dont know why this happening. Also im new to flutter. thanks in advance.

```
List<String> myList = [];
```

inside build(stateful widget),

```
onTap: (){
setState((){
myList.add("newstring");
});}
```

Comment: Also help with this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70344260/how-can-i-achieve-favorites-implementation-to-flutter-app-without-firebase-im

Comment: https://flutterbyexample.com/lesson/adding-elements-add-and-insert-all

Answer (score 6):

you should copy objects in setState, in your case it should be

```
onTap: () {
    setState((){
        myList = [...state.myList, "newstring"];
    });
}
```

Comment: kindly explain `...state.myList` since it is giving error. Thanks

Comment: it is called spread operator, will copy list object

Comment: details here: https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#spread-operator

Comment: The point being that by assigning an extended copy of the list instead of just adding an element, the list identity changes which causes rebuild.

Answer (score -4):

->  You Perform  This Type  Exaple   Dart  Pad
EX:

```
 void main() {
      List<String>   OneData  = ['one','two','three'];  
      List<String>  TwoData = []; 
      TwoData.add('one'); 
      print(TwoData);
    }
```

Comment: your answer doesn't contain any solution